# Optimization, Are all points feasible if there is only one constraint?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, constraints

The definition of a regular point is as follows :

> [image]

If instead of having multiple constraints there is only one, we would have

$$
D\;h(x) = \nabla h_1(x)^T
$$

Would all points then be regular for this vector? As there is only one?

Comment: A single vector can be linearly dependent if that vector is the zero vector. So you have to watch out for that case.

Comment: Also it’s not your work, but I think that $0$ in the last line of the image should be an $m$.